# show information from mysql in 4*4 table in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have a table with one field which has 16 record. I wanna show them in a 4*4 table but i don't know how do it. My code shows them in one row.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="mybg">
            <?php   
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tutors_students where tutor_id = ? and ok=1 ORDER BY date DESC ";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($userid));
            $data =  $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach($q->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) {  ?>
            <th><?php echo $v['date'];?> </th>
            <?php   }
            Database::disconnect();
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="mybg1">
```

Comment: add a counter, increase in every loop, once it's 3 add a `"</tr><tr>"` to the output, reset the counter to 0

Comment: 4 columns and 4 rows. maybe my rows be more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a counter, increase that in every loop;
Once you have 4 colums print a new row and reset the counter:

```
$cnt=0;
foreach($q->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) {
    $cnt++;
    echo '<th>'. $v['date'].'</th>';

    if($cnt===4) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        $cnt=0;
    }
}
```